# Permission denied using multiple Github user SSH keys

Tags: git, github, ssh

Folks, it’s my first time to use multiple SSH keys for multiple users. I point out in the following all the steps I carried out:

Assume I have 2 GitHub users attached to 2 different GitHub accounts, `user1` and `user2` respectively.

**1**. I was able to generate different SSH keys for each user

**2**. Similarly, I have uploaded the respective private keys to each user account

**3**. Thereafter, I set up the SSH config file like this:

```
Host user1.github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_git_user1      # private key user1

Host user2.github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_git_ user2      # private key user2
```

**4**. I cleared the SSH cache and load the new identities

```
ssh-add -D *
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_git_ user1
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_git_ user2
```

and after issuing `ssh-add -l`, both keys are listed down

**5**. Whenever I create a new repo to any of them, I’m used to updating the local file `.git/config`. 
For instance, I append the following config for each repo related to user1 manually:

```
[user]
    name = user1
    mail = user1@mail.com
```

and I did the same for user2 repositories

The problem is, whenever I load both keys at **`step 4`**, I was unable to do `git push` using `user1`, and it throws this error. 
Let’s assume `repo_user1` is a newly created repository related to user1.

```
ERROR: Permission to user1/repo_user1.git denied to user2
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I doubt the problem is, git failed to load the **right key of the current user** cause when I redo **`step 4`** and omit to load the second key, it works fine. The error also says `denied to user2` though my config is set for `user1`.

I really appreciate any workaround to avoid repeating the same steps each time I push my update.

Thanks,

Comment: The issue here is that as far as ssh is concerned, they are both the same user named "git".

Comment: @jordanm could you give more detail?

Comment: If you run `git remote get-url origin` on your repos, you will see it always shows `git@github.com`. The ssh username is always "git" with github.

Answer (score 4):

Try with the follwoign ~/.ssh/config file:

```sh
Host user1.github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_git_user1      # private key user1
    User git

Host user2.github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_git_ user2      # private key user2 
    User git
```

Then, for repo1, make sure to use the right SSH URL:

```
cd /path/to/repo1
git remote set-url user1.github.com:user1/repo_user1.git
```

That will use `~/.ssh/id_git_user1`.